# Modal not working properly after validating it from POST Action

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am using a Modal Partial View in my app. I am validating my model if it has errors I am returning the model using ModelState.AddModelError() but it is not working fine. Also, I could not load the SelectLists.

```
public ActionResult StockOut(StockOut model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var stock = (from s in db.Stocks where s.ProductId == model.ProductId select s).FirstOrDefault();
            if (stock.Quantity > 0 && model.Quantity <= stock.Quantity)
            {
                var weight = ((from p in db.Products where p.Id == model.ProductId select p).FirstOrDefault().NetWeight) * model.Quantity;
                stock.Quantity -= model.Quantity;
                stock.TotalWeight -= weight;
                StockOut entity = new StockOut()
                {
                    DriverId = model.DriverId,
                    LastUpdated = DateTime.Now,
                    ProductId = model.ProductId,
                    Quantity = model.Quantity,
                    TotalWeight = weight
                };
                db.StockOut.Add(entity);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Quantity", "Please Enter A Valid Quantity");
                ViewBag.ProductId = new SelectList(db.Products.ToList(), model.ProductId);
                ViewBag.DriverId = new SelectList(db.Products.ToList(), model.DriverId);
            }
        }
        ViewBag.ProductId = new SelectList(db.Products.ToList(), model.ProductId);
        ViewBag.DriverId = new SelectList(db.Users.ToList(), model.DriverId);
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

##### Before Submitting:

[image: image of site Before Submiting]

##### After Getting an Error

[image: image of site After Getting an Error. Formatting has disappeared.]

Comment: Its nearly impossible to debug an application by images unfortunately

Comment: We can't guess what you are doing (wrong or right) if you don't show us some code

Comment: Sorry guys I thought I have added it. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix you select lists, you are  creating them twice, remove one set (inside of  if)

```
ViewBag.ProductId = new SelectList(db.Products.ToList(),"Id", "Name" , model.ProductId);

///Are you sure that you have have to use products again?

ViewBag.DriverId = new SelectList(db.Products.ToList(),"Id", 
"Name" , model.DriverId);
```

and if you want to use AddModelError you have to add to form

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

Comment: No, I have to create them twice. the if condition will work if the model state is true. and then the second set will be needed again because it is going back to the view. If I delete the second set there will be an error because the view could not find the lists.